# How to properly deploy python project that uses pywin32 modules

Tags: python, deployment, pywin32, pynsist

I recently finished a project for a client that essentially is a scrolling wall calendar. It uses a module called [pywebview](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview) that uses some pywin32 modules which I don't know how to properly install on the clients computer unless I did it myself. I've been able to [find the error in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459325/py2exe-importerror-no-module-named-shell), but only in regards to py2exe, and I'm reluctant to use py2exe as its my experience that it drastically slows down my programs (I had been trying to use pynsist). If anybody can help, I'd appreciate it. If it helps, the project can be accessed [here](https://github.com/ironman5366/Scrolling-Program)

Comment: Looking through the available information, I think that if you list both `win32com` and `win32comext` under 'packages' in the config file, it should work. But I haven't tried that. If you do get it working, it would be good to have a pywebview example in the pynsist repository.

Comment: I'm getting a no moudle found for win32comext

Comment: And if I try to just do win32com I end up going down a chain of modules that ends with the error referenced in the py2exe link.

Comment: Ah, it looks like `win32comext` is not importable itself. Try finding the directory called `win32comext` and copying it inside a folder called `pynsist_pkgs`, next to your `installer.cfg` file (so the directory structure is like [this](http://pastebin.com/9nxxS9Yx). Any files in `pynsist_pkgs` will be included in the installer along with the packages you specify to include.

Comment: Will try tomorrow, thanks

Comment: `win32comext` couldn't be imported. After a variety of other attempted fixes, I ended up just having to suck it up and go with py2exe.

Comment: I think it should be possible to do it using `pynsist_pkgs`; it's not an importable package, so you can't list it in packages. But I haven't had time to check on a Windows machine.

Comment: I'll check again, but I believe I did that and something was still trying to import it but couldn't. Don't quite remember though as this happened last week. In any case py2exe worked surprisingly well and is faster then my previous experience led me to expect.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to import that but the same modules from before. So I don't think it's being accessed.

Comment: I tried making a pywebview example for Pynsist; I got past this problem and was able to get it working, but there are still some issues: https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/pull/57